# Asp Timer with AsyncPostBackTrigger on child ascx page causes Default.aspx to reload

Tags: asp.net, timer, ascx

What i'm trying to accomplish is a partial page reload on just an child ascx control.  However, if I put a break on default.aspx on Page Load the break will hit on the timer tick.  My ideal scenario would be the default.aspx never reloads.

Default.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
    </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Put your JavaScript code here.
</script>
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DynLabel"></asp:Label>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderDyn" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Guid g;
        g = Guid.NewGuid();
        DynLabel.Text = g.ToString();
        PlaceHolderDyn.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/Docks/DynControl.ascx"));


    }


}
```

`DynControl.ascx`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DynControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Docks_DynControl" %>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
<AjaxSettings>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="Timer1">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1">
            </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="DropDownList1">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel2"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DynamicPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Labelrunat="server" ID="DynamiclabelAscx"/>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`DynControl.aspx.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

public partial class Docks_DynControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
     public void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Guid g;
        g = Guid.NewGuid();
        DynamiclabelAscx.Text = g.ToString();


    }


}
```

So basically the label on the Default.aspx will be static, only load once, and the timer will reload the label on the ascx and it will always change.  That works, but how can i prevent the default.aspx from reloading on the timer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, here is the answer to your question:

> An asynchronous postback behaves much like a synchronous postback. All
>   the server page life-cycle events occur, and view state and form data
>   are preserved. However, in the rendering phase, only the contents of
>   the UpdatePanel control are sent to the browser. The rest of the page
>   remains unchanged.

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx)

So wrapping the Default.aspx `Page_Load` method in `!IsPostBack` seems to be the way to go:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Guid g;
        g = Guid.NewGuid();
        DynLabel.Text = g.ToString();
        PlaceHolderDyn.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/Docks/DynControl.ascx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Scott thats the thing, why do I have to if only a partial update is happening?

Comment: Scott - i am using UpdatePanel

Comment: @Mike - I added another possible cause of your issue to my answer.

Comment: yeah even if you completely remove all references on default.aspx of those and even add PartialRendering it still requires !IsPostBack

Comment: What if you tried `Timer1_Tick` instead of `Tick` in your `AsyncPostBackTrigger` markup?

Comment: Could not find an event named 'Timer1_Tick' on associated control 'Timer1' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'Panel1'.

Comment: Ok just making sure it didn't require the actual Handler name.  I had a thought though, what if you put the Timer in its own UpdatePanel?

Comment: I updated my answer. Seems that all life-cycle events still occur regardless of what's being rendered back.  So the the easiest way to not have your `Page_Load` method fire is to wrap it in `!IsPostBack`.

Comment: Scott - I just read your update but how does work in terms on things like SignalR chat?

Comment: Not sure. Never used SignalR chat. I'm just trying to answer your question of _how can i prevent the default.aspx from reloading on the timer?_

Comment: Scott - LOL thanks, but the postback is whats killing the SignalR chat

Comment: Scott - maybe thats the key it needs to be two seperate pages and the one page loads an Iframe...

Comment: Possibly, or you could create a Master Page / Content Page solution.

Comment: I'm just saying its a cleaner solution in terms of being able to share content that your content pages and/or user controls would need.  It could eliminate some other issue that is contributing to your problem.  I just don't see how the PostBack is the actual issue.  The life cycle is the life cycle.  Your `Page_Load` event is going to be fired regardless of full or partial.  That's why you use `!IsPostBack`.  There has to be something in the way you have designed the markup or code behind elsewhere that is causing the issue.

Comment: Scott - thanks for all the solutions.  However, I just tried Iframe = "default2.aspx" and because the second page has all the triggers and such, the first page enever causes a postback, so essentially you just need to figure out a way to pass parameters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott for the extended conversation.

The best way I've figured out to prevent postback is to have everything contained in that additional control aspx/ascx in an IFrame that points to that aspx.  This will cause only that page to render any postback.